# I want a Query that show all of S# and Sname that they have all red P#

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database :

```
S(S#,Sname,status,City)

P(P#,Pname,color,weight,city)

SP(S#,P#,number)
```

I want a Query that show all of S# and Sname that they have all red P#.

Example:

```
S:

S1 Sname1 status1 city(1)

S2 Sname2 status2 City(2)

S3 Sname3 status3 City(3)


P:

P1 Pname1 red weight1 city(n)

P2 Pname2 blue weight2 city(n)

P3 Pname3 green weight3 city(n)

P4 Pname4 red weight4 city(n)


SP:

S1 P1 number1

S1 p4 number2

s2 p1 number3

s3 p3 number4

S3 p1 number5

S3 p4 number6

S2 p2 number7
```

Expected answer:

```
S1,Sname1

S3,Sname3
```

Comment: You need a simple join between the three tables.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please write your query.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join the table and get the distinct rows from table S:

```
select distinct s.s_id,
    s.name
from s
join sp on s.s_id = sp.s_id
join p on sp.p_id = p.p_id
where p.color = 'red'
```

Comment: The main condition is not met in this query. In my example, this query S2 is shown. I Want a Query that Show "Sname's that they **have all of** red P#".